# What does the value of data-p means in JSSOR demos and examples?

Tags: jssor

I've looked through all the examples and demos and browsed the documentation, but I can't find the meaning of the numerical values of data-p attribute inside of some DIV tags. I see the numbers such as 816.0, 170.0 and 112.50, but can't figure it out. What does it mean?

Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means css style perspective.

170 means

```
style="perspective: 170px;"
```